# opencv in python: a very strange error. What is the difference between creating a new image with np.zeros and simply copying the existing image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose I have a image loaded in python. I understand since a colored image in python is no more than a three-dimensional array, I attempted to create a new image that only contains a few selected pixel values from the loaded image. However this is really not working well. Please allow me to demonstrate with a very simple example.

Suppose that my original image "img" is a 20x20x3 matrix with all elements equal to 0.

```
img2 = np.zeros(img.shape)
img2[0:5,0:5] = [100,0,0]
```

With this I am assuming that the output on imshow should have a blacked out image but with a blue square on the top left corner. This is working well.

However, if I change to

```
img2 = np.zeros(img.shape)
img2[0:5,0:5] = [100,100,1]
```

This shows a completely white square on the top left corner, with the rest blacked out. However, BGR = [100,100,1] (opencv in python processes image in BGR space instead of RGB) should not be white!

This problem is immediately fixed with

```
img2 = img.copy()
img2[0:5,0:5] = [100,100,1]
```

with this I get a square on the top left corner with the correct pixel value.

Could someone let me know what is the fundamental difference between creating a new numpy ndarray with exactly the same shape as the original image, and fill in the desired values; and simply making a copy of the original img matrix? Why it works well with BGR = [100,0,0] but not with [100,100,1]?

Thanks

Comment: do you get the same behaviour with np.zeros_like instead of np.zeros ?

Comment: @DanPatterson WOW I just tried np.zeros_like and it immediately fixed the problem... what are the differences between np.zeros and np.zeros_like? and I still dont get why np.zeros would show me the white color with bgr = [100,100,1]

Comment: Well from the help there are other *like functions ones_like : Return an array of ones with shape and type of input.
    empty_like : Return an empty array with shape and type of input.
    zeros : Return a new array setting values to zero.
    ones : Return a new array setting values to one.
    empty : Return a new uninitialized array.    I prefer to use the like incarnations if I want to ensure that the resultant has the characteristics of the input.  I don't remember getting caught, but I just assumed the *like* versions were there for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please explain how you created `img` as well? One reason for the different behavior might be that `img2` does not have the same data type (`img2.dtype`) as `img`, and that the visualization function that you use (could you also tell us which function you call to display the image?) has a different behavior when you pass integer-type or floating-point-type images (like, for integer-type, the color range will be between 0 and 255, while for floats, it will be between `img2.min()` and `img2.max()`.

When you're using `np.zeros`, if you don't specify the `dtype` keyword argument the output array will have a float dtype. On the other hand, using `np.zeros_like` keeps the same dtype as the input array. I would suspect that in your example `img` is an image of integers, and that your visualization procedure behaves differently for integer and float images.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. Indeed my img was integer (it is just a black image), and I solved the problem by specifying it to be an integer np.zeros(img.shape,int).

Comment: I used "imshow" for display. Does this function has such a nasty behavior? seriously this is so bad!

Comment: ``imshow`` from which package? ``matplotlib`` has an ``imshow`` function, ``scikit-image```as well... As for the nasty behavior, it's a tradeoff between doing magics for the user, and resulting in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Hi it is from the cv2 package in python

Comment: to be honest I would rather do a bit more work and write a bit more code myself, than having a near almighty function but occasionally results in such an unexpected error and get me stuck for hours... after all, who would have thought of such function only working properly with integer values?